# Update binding of property in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to update a property using a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, but I think my conceptual understanding of how this works might be a bit flawed. As I'm new to WPF and silver-light.

So, let me explain, I have a property that is set to 0, but after some time a thread changes the value from 0 to 9 internally, but despite the change in value, this property never gets updated in the actual view and I don't know why! Even after I implement a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` there is no change, but if I log the property it shows that the value is in fact 9

So here is the snippet of code that implements `PropertyChangedEventHandler`:

```
public class CustomColumn : IColumnViewable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        Foo.log.Error(": start on property change");
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        Foo.log.Error(": end on property change");
    }
    public static string _total;
    public string total { get { return _total; } set {  _total = value; OnPropertyChanged("total"); Foo.log.Error(": property change"); } }
    ...
}
```

Here is part of my xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ColumnView">
    <UserControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            ...
            <RichTextBox Margin="5,2,5,2">
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=total, Mode=OneWay}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30"  />
                    <Run Text=" total clicks" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBox>
           ...
            <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding Path=timeline}" ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=timelineView.ContentTemplate}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl> 
</DataTemplate>
```

And I do this on initialize:

```
CustomColumn content = new CustomColumn();
content.total = "0";
```

And then I pass the object to a thread which at some point does this:

```
 content.total = "9";
 Foo.log.Error("value is "+content.total);
```

And the property never updates and I don't know why - any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged` should only be called after the value has been set, not before.

Comment: I made that change but with no luck the property still does not update :(

Comment: Of course it does not, that is why i said this in a comment. Do you get any binding errors in the Output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: Oh oops :P well this might be a noob thought but i was thinking it might be my object pass, I pass the object named 'content' from one class to another, does C# pass by reference and if so does this effect the binding?

Comment: Yes, it passes the reference and it should affect the binding.

Comment: no i dont get any binding errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the details of your question, you are updating a UI bound value on a background thread. You need to make that happen on the UI thread or the change will not be visible. In one of our WPF apps random updates were disappearing until we realised this.

We do a lot of multi-threading in our Silverlight (and WPF) apps so to avoid this problem, we implemented our notify helper in a base class like the one below (other stuff trimmed out). It dispatches all notify messages on the main UI thread. Give it a try:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected delegate void OnUiThreadDelegate();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // Ensure property change is on the UI thread
            this.OnUiThread(() => this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
        }
    }

    protected void OnUiThread(OnUiThreadDelegate onUiThreadDelegate)
    {
        // Are we on the Dispatcher thread ?
        if (Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            onUiThreadDelegate();
        }
        else
        {
            // We are not on the UI Dispatcher thread so invoke the call on it.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(onUiThreadDelegate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i found that this worked in almost all cases (there is one case that im still working to resolve but for most purposes this will work for anyone that has this issue in the future) thanks @HiTechMagic!

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show where you make the object the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of your controls, which is necessary for your bindings which do not specify another source and hence bind to the `DataContext`.

```
CustomColumn content = new CustomColumn();
content.total = "0";
```

Do you have any line after this where this object is passed to your view?

Comment: I do this: `context.Space.AddColumn(this, content);
            ItemProvider.content = content;` - also the value of 0 does show up initially as 0 in the view but it never changes to 9, wouldn't the binding break initially as well if it was incorrect instead of just breaking afterwords?

Comment: Yes, it should break right away; Does it show other initial values, e.g. if you change the field declaration to `... _total = 9`?

Comment: i tried that and the value is still displayed as 0 probably because i overwrite that on initialize BUT i think i know what might be my problem and maybe u can verify my thoughts - so the view shows the value as 0 then i change the value to 9 and the view still shows it as 0 BUT if i move away from that control i.e. press a button that takes me to another frame, and then i go back to the frame that had the 0 it is now a 9 - so maybe i have to redraw the frame? (this is probably not the right terminology but i hope you understand what i mean)